Unable to perform Junit Parameterized test execution getting java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class
Getting the following error when running Parameterized test.  Please help.
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParsingUtilTest {
    

    @Test
    @Parameters
    public List<String[]> parameters() {
            return Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{"wrtier { type=file  }; reader { type=DB, query=update asdsadsad  }; processor { type = None }", "{wrtier={type=file}, reader={type=DB, query=update asdsadsad}, processor={type=None}}"},
                new String[]{"wrtier { type=file  };wrtier { type=file  }", "{wrtier={type=file}, wrtier_1={type=file}}"},
                new String[]{"", "{}"},
                new String[]{"{}", ""},
                new String[]{";wrtier { type=file  }", "{}"},
                new String[]{"{}", ";wrtier { type=file  }"},
                new String[]{"wrtier type=file}", "wrtier type=file}"},
                new String[]{"{w={t=f}}", "w{t=f}"}
            );
        }
    public void testParseStepSequenceInMapCnd1(String level, String expected ) throws Exception {
        CnfStep step = new CnfStep();
        step.setStepParams(level);
        assertEquals(expected, ParsingUtil.parseStepSequenceInMap( step.getStepParams() ).toString());
    }

java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class com.nyl.group.bpbilling.util.ParsingUtilTest
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)


The exception reports correctly that no static parameters() method can be found. Normally in JUNIT I would have expected to see the test method with @ParameterizedTest tag:
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("parameters")
public void testParseStepSequenceInMapCnd1(String level, String expected ) throws Exception {
}

and the parameters can be static no-args method of same class:
private static List<String[]> parameters() {
    ...
}

